# Running django factory in a loop doesnt create the required number of instances when the loop is run for really long

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-models, factory

So, consider the sample model:

```
class TestModal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and the related factory created as:

```
class TestModalFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModal
```

Now, the problem is if I am creating 3000 instances in a loop as shown below:

```
for _ in range(3000):
    TestModalFactory()
```

It doesn't create 3000 instances but creates somewhere around 2950 instances of `TestModal`. I would love it if someone could help.

Comment: Why do you think it's not creating 3000 instances?

Comment: That is the problem that it isnt creating the required number of instances

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say there's a bug elsewhere in how you're counting the number of instances. I'm generally pretty sure the factory is working as documented.